# Suspend does not work on HP Pavilion g6 with Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, suspend, hp-pavilion

I've installed Ubuntu 14.04 on an HP Pavilion g6 laptop. Most things seem to work except suspend and the backlight brightness. I can live with the backlight issue for now.

I have tried using the default graphics driver as well as the restricted drivers and AMD's latest Catalyst drivers; no luck. When I suspend the system, the screen goes blank and the backlight flashes on and off a few times. Then after a few seconds, the login screen appears. If I close the lid, I assume the same thing happens because the fans never go off. I'm not sure what the issue is. Does anyone know how to fix it or how I can go about diagnosing the problem (e.g. logs to check, etc.)?

Answer (score 0):

I recently tried updating the kernel on my pavilion g6 and it seems it's been fixed.
Try [updating to the latest kernel](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/MainlineBuilds), which as of this writing is 3.15.0-031500rc2